# How to color the child elements of an hovered element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this senario:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.wbbBoard:hover>.containerHeadline>h3>a,
.wbbBoardList .wbbBoard:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wbbBoardList">
  <li data-board-id="4" class="wbbBoardContainer wbbDepth2">
    <div class="wbbBoardNode1 wbbBoard box32">
      <span class="icon icon32 icon-lock"></span>
      <div>
        <div class="containerHeadline">
          <h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
          <p class="wbbBoardDescription">description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I hover over the element I want the Title to display another color, like the description is being changed. How can I do that with css or less?

Comment: `.wbbBoard:hover h3 {color: #f00}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector `.wbbBoard:hover > .containerHeadline > h3 > a` is wrong as `.containerHeadline` is not an immediate child of `.wbbBoard`

> [**`>` select the immediate child elements...**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Use `.wbbBoard:hover .containerHeadline > h3 > a`

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.wbbBoard:hover .containerHeadline>h3>a,
.wbbBoardList .wbbBoard:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wbbBoardList">
  <li data-board-id="4" class="wbbBoardContainer wbbDepth2">
    <div class="wbbBoardNode1 wbbBoard box32">
      <span class="icon icon32 icon-lock"></span>
      <div>
        <div class="containerHeadline">
          <h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
          <p class="wbbBoardDescription">description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply below css to make it work properly

```
.wbbBoardList .wbbBoard:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.wbbBoard:hover > .containerHeadline > h3 > a,
.wbbBoardList .wbbBoard:hover {
 color: #f4f4f4;
 background-color: #333;
}
.wbbBoardList .wbbBoard:hover a {
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wbbBoardList">
     
     
   <li data-board-id="4" class="wbbBoardContainer wbbDepth2">
   <div class="wbbBoardNode1 wbbBoard box32">
    <span class="icon icon32 icon-lock"></span>
    
    <div>
     <div class="containerHeadline">
      <h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
      <p class="wbbBoardDescription">description</p>
     </div>
     
          
          
     
    </div>
   </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I only understand the question that, you want to change the title color, on hover the **wbbBoard**. If you want to make this change, kindly modify the CSS with

```
.wbbBoard:hover .conatinerHeadline h3 a {
  color: green;
}
```

I think this will help out to this problem.